# Printer Properties Dialog is not showing in MS-Word 2010

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010

In Microsoft Word 2010, I can't open the printer properties dialog. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, the print dialog is opened. When I try to click on "Properties" beneath the printer, nothing happens. Any ideas?

The print properties dialog works just fine in other programs, like Firefox or even Outlook 2010. I have one USB and a few networked printers. The problem occurs when opening pre-created documents *and* new documents.

Comment: Is it a network printer?

Comment: Well, I have a couple different printers: one USB, and a few network printers. The printer properties dialog box doesn't work for ANY of them in Word, but it does work for ALL of them in other programs, which suggests to me that the problem is with Word itself.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add those details.

Comment: I thought that those details were irrelevant because, as I indicated, the print properties dialog _doesn't_ work in Word but _does_ work in other programs; it seemed to me that networked vs USB had nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: It helps to know you have multiple printers connected in various ways to rule out network or local connection issues, and keeps people form asking the question. Now...Is this a new problem or has this always happened in Word? Does it happen with all documents?

Comment: My computer used to have Office 2003, but the company recently pushed out Office 2010. It didn't used to be a problem with 2003, but it's been a problem since they pushed out 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very localized and can be caused by your specific computer, Office install, printers, etc. This means it will be difficult to give you a definitive answer. What I believe it could be is a compatibility issue. Word supposedly can cause issues with printer properties when in `Compatibility Mode`.

Here is more info about [Compatibility Mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2117661). This article also discusses using the **"Check for Issues"** feature which might help you find out what it happening.

**Here is what you can try...**

1. Check compatibility
2. Save the document to the new format (docx)
3. Make sure you have all the updates for Office installed
4. If you are the only one having this issue, consider a [repair of the install](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/repair-or-remove-office-HA010357402.aspx)
5. Contact whomever installed Office for you and have them troubleshoot this.

Comment: Well, the problem occurs even when creating _new_ documents, which, of course, means that it wouldn't be operating in compatibility mode, would it?

Comment: Again, those are details which would be good to know in order to help troubleshoot this. Move to the next suggestion in my list.